# Angular 2 import 3rd party library

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I try to import 3rd party library synaptic.
Library is writed in java script, and i have .d.ts file.

I did:
npm install synaptic --save
npm install @types/synaptic --save

import * as synaptic from 'synaptic'  in my component

And i still get:
GET http://localhost:3000/synaptic 404 (Not Found)"

Can you help me?

Comment: You must use {   } for import the modules

Comment: even when i import with {} i.e. import { Neuron } from 'synaptic', i got 404

Answer (score 0):

When angular compiles the it won't keep the traditional JS routes. After your import you should be able to access the 3rd parties features in the component.

Try syanptic : Syanptic 
and then do whatever you want with this.syanptic

Comment: yeah it will always be 404. if you specify want a  http://localhost:3000/synaptic you will need to make a route to /synaptic and populate it in a way you want